# AWS ALB logout sessions failing

Tags: amazon-ec2, single-sign-on, amazon-route53, janrain, aws-alb

I have recently encountered a scenario where my session is restored even after clicking logout link(domain/logout) in my site(from frontend) which is pointed to an ALB in aws having cookies(AWSALB, JSESSION etc).Basically the session is restored even after my logout link(from UI) is clicked and what wondered me is when I forcefully hit /logout in URL then the session is logged out without any issue(session is not restored), Also, that is not the case when I tested the same site with a host entry pointing to one of the servers in ALB, the same logout link(from UI) works fine without any session resstoration from sso.js file.
Can someone help me figure out where could be the flaw.

Comment: Can you give your code ? or Explain clearly.. As per my understanding SSO is not getting logged out. then try this method after logout. janrain.capture.ui.endCaptureSession();

Comment: It sounds like the logout method in the sso.js file (or if you are using the capture/engage widget) is not getting a chance to call the necessary end points.  It's hard to give any sort of answer without being able to review the full configuration.  Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was correct @PBICS. We were able to fix by tweaking sso.js